# Weka and unknown datatype

Tags: java, mysql, database, types, weka

After successfully uploading mysql database into weka and applying a simple query, when I press ok, I get:

> Couldn't read from database:
> Unknown data type: INT. Add entry in weka/expirement/DatabaseUtils.props.
> if the type contains blanks, either escape them with a backslash or use underscores instead of blanks"

I've searched effortlessly for a solution but nothing works.

- I tried adding int=5 in the DatabaseUtlis.props file
- I tried int_unsigned=5

my databaseutils.props file looks like this

```
# Database settings for MySQL 3.23.x, 4.x
#
# General information on database access can be found here:
# https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/databases/
#
# url:     http://www.mysql.com/
# jdbc:    http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/j/
# author:  Fracpete (fracpete at waikato dot ac dot nz)
# version: $Revision: 15255 $

# JDBC driver (comma-separated list)
jdbcDriver=org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver

# database URL
jdbcURL=jdbc:mysql://zalpha-db.cei00brrdcsc.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com/mqdata

# specific data types
# string, getString() = 0;    --> nominal
# boolean, getBoolean() = 1;  --> nominal
# double, getDouble() = 2;    --> numeric
# byte, getByte() = 3;        --> numeric
# short, getByte()= 4;        --> numeric
# int, getInteger() = 5;      --> numeric
# long, getLong() = 6;        --> numeric
# float, getFloat() = 7;      --> numeric
# date, getDate() = 8;        --> date
# text, getString() = 9;      --> string
# time, getTime() = 10;       --> date
# timestamp, getTime() = 11;  --> date



INT = 5

# other options
CREATE_DOUBLE=DOUBLE
CREATE_STRING=TEXT
CREATE_INT=INT
CREATE_DATE=DATETIME
DateFormat=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
checkUpperCaseNames=false
checkLowerCaseNames=false
checkForTable=true

# All the reserved keywords for this database
# Based on the keywords listed at the following URL (2009-04-13):
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-0.html
Keywords=\
  ADD,\
  ALL,\
  ALTER,\
  ANALYZE,\
  AND,\
  AS,\
  ASC,\
  ASENSITIVE,\
  BEFORE,\
  BETWEEN,\
  BIGINT,\
  BINARY,\
  BLOB,\
  BOTH,\
  BY,\
  CALL,\
  CASCADE,\
  CASE,\
  CHANGE,\
  CHAR,\
  CHARACTER,\
  CHECK,\
  COLLATE,\
  COLUMN,\
  COLUMNS,\
  CONDITION,\
  CONNECTION,\
  CONSTRAINT,\
  CONTINUE,\
  CONVERT,\
  CREATE,\
  CROSS,\
  CURRENT_DATE,\
  CURRENT_TIME,\
  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,\
  CURRENT_USER,\
  CURSOR,\
  DATABASE,\
  DATABASES,\
  DAY_HOUR,\
  DAY_MICROSECOND,\
  DAY_MINUTE,\
  DAY_SECOND,\
  DEC,\
  DECIMAL,\
  DECLARE,\
  DEFAULT,\
  DELAYED,\
  DELETE,\
  DESC,\
  DESCRIBE,\
  DETERMINISTIC,\
  DISTINCT,\
  DISTINCTROW,\
  DIV,\
  DOUBLE,\
  DROP,\
  DUAL,\
  EACH,\
  ELSE,\
  ELSEIF,\
  ENCLOSED,\
  ESCAPED,\
  EXISTS,\
  EXIT,\
  EXPLAIN,\
  FALSE,\
  FETCH,\
  FIELDS,\
  FLOAT,\
  FLOAT4,\
  FLOAT8,\
  FOR,\
  FORCE,\
  FOREIGN,\
  FROM,\
  FULLTEXT,\
  GOTO,\
  GRANT,\
  GROUP,\
  HAVING,\
  HIGH_PRIORITY,\
  HOUR_MICROSECOND,\
  HOUR_MINUTE,\
  HOUR_SECOND,\
  IF,\
  IGNORE,\
  IN,\
  INDEX,\
  INFILE,\
  INNER,\
  INOUT,\
  INSENSITIVE,\
  INSERT,\
  INT,\
  INT1,\
  INT2,\
  INT3,\
  INT4,\
  INT8,\
  INTEGER,\
  INTERVAL,\
  INTO,\
  IS,\
  ITERATE,\
  JOIN,\
  KEY,\
  KEYS,\
  KILL,\
  LABEL,\
  LEADING,\
  LEAVE,\
  LEFT,\
  LIKE,\
  LIMIT,\
  LINES,\
  LOAD,\
  LOCALTIME,\
  LOCALTIMESTAMP,\
  LOCK,\
  LONG,\
  LONGBLOB,\
  LONGTEXT,\
  LOOP,\
  LOW_PRIORITY,\
  MATCH,\
  MEDIUMBLOB,\
  MEDIUMINT,\
  MEDIUMTEXT,\
  MIDDLEINT,\
  MINUTE_MICROSECOND,\
  MINUTE_SECOND,\
  MOD,\
  MODIFIES,\
  NATURAL,\
  NOT,\
  NO_WRITE_TO_BINLOG,\
  NULL,\
  NUMERIC,\
  ON,\
  OPTIMIZE,\
  OPTION,\
  OPTIONALLY,\
  OR,\
  ORDER,\
  OUT,\
  OUTER,\
  OUTFILE,\
  PRECISION,\
  PRIMARY,\
  PRIVILEGES,\
  PROCEDURE,\
  PURGE,\
  READ,\
  READS,\
  REAL,\
  REFERENCES,\
  REGEXP,\
  RELEASE,\
  RENAME,\
  REPEAT,\
  REPLACE,\
  REQUIRE,\
  RESTRICT,\
  RETURN,\
  REVOKE,\
  RIGHT,\
  RLIKE,\
  SCHEMA,\
  SCHEMAS,\
  SECOND_MICROSECOND,\
  SELECT,\
  SENSITIVE,\
  SEPARATOR,\
  SET,\
  SHOW,\
  SMALLINT,\
  SONAME,\
  SPATIAL,\
  SPECIFIC,\
  SQL,\
  SQLEXCEPTION,\
  SQLSTATE,\
  SQLWARNING,\
  SQL_BIG_RESULT,\
  SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS,\
  SQL_SMALL_RESULT,\
  SSL,\
  STARTING,\
  STRAIGHT_JOIN,\
  TABLE,\
  TABLES,\
  TERMINATED,\
  THEN,\
  TINYBLOB,\
  TINYINT,\
  TINYTEXT,\
  TO,\
  TRAILING,\
  TRIGGER,\
  TRUE,\
  UNDO,\
  UNION,\
  UNIQUE,\
  UNLOCK,\
  UNSIGNED,\
  UPDATE,\
  UPGRADE,\
  USAGE,\
  USE,\
  USING,\
  UTC_DATE,\
  UTC_TIME,\
  UTC_TIMESTAMP,\
  VALUES,\
  VARBINARY,\
  VARCHAR,\
  VARCHARACTER,\
  VARYING,\
  WHEN,\
  WHERE,\
  WHILE,\
  WITH,\
  WRITE,\
  XOR,\
  YEAR_MONTH,\
  ZEROFILL

# The character to append to attribute names to avoid exceptions due to
# clashes between keywords and attribute names
KeywordsMaskChar=_

#flags for loading and saving instances using DatabaseLoader/Saver
nominalToStringLimit=50
idColumn=auto_generated_id
```

Anyone who's solved this issue or may know how to?

Comment: Without any of your code it will be hard to help you.

Comment: sorry about that, i added my databaseutils.prop file, maybe it could give a hint, cheers!!

Comment: I resolved the issue. I actually just had to add; INT=5 and INT_UNSIGNED=5 in the databaseutils.prop file. Just that in my case i was adding it in the mysql type file while i had to rather add it in the property project type file. cheers!!!

Comment: If you have the time then answer to your own question and then accept it as the good answer, this way this info will be available to others in the future. And as you improved the quality of your question it will be easier for others with same problem to find it.

Answer (score 1):

If that error message pops up, it means int datatype is not recognized. in order to fix this, you have to verify your databaseutils.prop file and add; INT=5 and INT_UNSIGNED=5. Note that you have to do that in the properties file and not the mysql type file.

Comment: yes works for me too after this.